# Update image from www/Upload/DP/image.png asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have a code for image upload and that working as expected, in my way image is DP display picture of user.

> Create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DP" class="control-label">Profile Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="DP" asp-for="DP" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="DP" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

> Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Profile profile, IFormFile DP)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var id = _userManager.GetUserName(HttpContext.User);                
                var fileName = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath +"/Upload/DP/", Path.GetFileName(id+".png"));                
                DP.CopyTo(new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Create));
                //profile.DP = fileName;
                ViewBag.fileName = fileName;              

                var create = new Profile {
                    userName = profile.userName,
                    uId = profile.uId,
                    rId = profile.rId,
                    Mobile = profile.Mobile,
                    Job = profile.Job,
                    City = profile.City,
                    Address = profile.Address,
                    dof = profile.dof,
                    DP = profile.DP = Path.GetFileName(id+".png"),
                    CreatedOn = profile.CreatedOn,
                    Status = profile.Status
                }; 
                    _context.Add(profile);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));                
            }
            ViewData["rId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<CharityRole>(), "rId", "Name", profile.rId);
            return View(profile);
        }
```

Question: How I can delete existing image and add a new one with same name bcz its display on user profile like:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Upload/DP/"+ _userManager.GetUserName(User)+".png")">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your post.

- You need to use `Using` for `FileStream`, otherwise, the filestream will be not disposed.

  ```
          using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
          {
              await DP.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
          }
  ```
- You need to pass `create` instead of `profile` to `_context.Add`.

Here is the complete demo code:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Profile profile, IFormFile DP)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var id = _userManager.GetUserName(HttpContext.User);
            var fileName = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath + "/Upload/DP/", Path.GetFileName(id + ".png"));
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await DP.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
            var create = new Profile
            {
                UserName = profile.UserName,                    
                DP = Path.GetFileName(id + ".png")                    
            };
            _context.Add(create);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(profile);
    }
```

Comment: Its ok, but my question is iwant to give a update profile pic option to my app user, how the new uploaded img will replace on exist img?

Comment: @JagdishKumar Have you tried above code? Does it not replace exist img? It will replace the img by filename.

Comment: Yes I tried above code and I know that's does't replace exist img, but I want it, to replace exist img of user. It already taking much time but I can't find perfect solution within now from last tow weeks. I tried to search on many website and youtube,ms docs also, simply CURD operation on img in asp.net core 2x. Can you help me to find out sol

Comment: @JagdishKumar I suggest you check the file name in wwwroot and the value for fileName and id, does it create a new file with the same name? Share the screen shot.

Comment: Exactly the img will create with same user id every time. when first time user register with profile img, and i done it with above code, after register i want to give a change profile img  option to user i mean replace user new img with same id that i assign registration time.